# Getting mysql data into a var array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Im using MySQL to obtain data into `$username` and `$chance`.

There are two usernames in the data but it only loads the first one.

```
var data = [
    {
         "name" : "<?php echo $username; ?>", 
         "hvalue" : <?php echo $chance; ?> 
    },
];
```

Comment: *Looks into his magic 8-ball* Your question is hazy, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Apparently you have not read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully. Brad, put yourself in our shoes. Do you think we're magicians, knowing exactly what you think, how your entire code works? **WHERE** does the data come from and **HOW** did you implement it and **WHAT** library's did you use for your pie chart, etc, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: I just want to know if that var array will get more than 1 $username and $chance or just 1? do i need to use a function like

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { ??

Comment: From what we can see, only 1. If your $username is an array, it probably won't print.

Answer (score 1):

To give a correct answer, we'll have to know what your variables `$username` and `$chance` exactly look like.

1. If you only have a string there, then only one value is possible.
2. If these variables are php arrays, you'll have to use `json_encode` to make a JSON array from them, before you can add them to your javascript object. (see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Anyway, the best way to send a PHP array to JS would be to create the whole array in PHP and then encode it to JSON in order to use all the values in JS.

`var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>`

More advanced: use an ajax request to avoid mixing up PHP an JS. But that's another story.